# jQuery validate showerrors display name

Tags: jquery, validation, errorplacement

I would like to add the name of the errors to my function so users know which fields they have to check.

This is my current function:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            var summary = "Please check following errors:";
            $.each(errorList, function() {
                summary += " * " + this.message + "<br>" ;
            });
            $('.errorbox').html(summary);
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            alert("submitted!");
        }
    });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I had no idea that i had to mark as solved. Thanks for letting me know!

The fiddle that mansuUK made in a previous question shows how its implemented now.

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/xTdYr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the Bassistance.de validation plugin, the easiest option to you is to add a friendly insturction message to the `title` parameter to each input control. This message will then be used as instruction text in the error message which appears. Here is an updated fiddle showing how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/xTdYr/3/

Alternatively, you can manually add the rules in the instanciation call of the `.validate()` method by using the `messages` parameter, details here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules

Comment: Recommended. If that isn't possible you could take the name attribute like `summary += " * " + this.element.name + ": "  + this.message + "\n";`

Comment: The form is being processed in different languages so using the messages is not the best option as I load the standard messages from the different language files. This way the error feedback looks quite the same. Is there really no option adding the name value to the feedback message?

Comment: Marco's answer worked for me. Thanks for the other suggestions people.

Answer (score 0):

Extend options with `messages: {name:"name error"}`

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gsBTC/

```
$('#newform').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.is(":radio")) {
            error.prependTo(element.parent());
        }
        else { // This is the default behavior of the script  
            error.insertAfter(element);
            console.log('here');
        }
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var summary = "You have the following errors: \n";
        $.each(errorList, function() {
            summary += " * " + this.message + "\n";
        });
        $('#errordiv').html(summary);
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }, 
    messages: {
     name   : "name error", 
     subject: "subject error",
     message: "message error"
   }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the form is multi-language. So I'm using the language files for the different languages. I could add a specific message for every element but i have 70 elements in 3 differernt langueges. That's alot of messages. So i prefer to use the general messages in each language and add the "name" so the user knows wich field is not ok.